# Anyway in TFS to check-in modified files which are not checked-out

Tags: tfs

Anyway in TFS to check-in modified files which are not checked-out.

I made modifications in some fo the files which are I didnt check-out.

In Sub version we can check-in only modified files is there any similar way here as well..

I am new to TFS

Comment: TFS will only check in modified files even if you checked out files you didn't change. But with TFS you really should check out files before you change them. That is why they are readonly.

Answer (score 8):

Ultimately, you do need to check out files before they can be checked in.  There's a couple of ways to do this - if you know exactly which files you've modified, you can simply check them out with the UI or with the command line client.

Of course, it's much easier to just let TFS determine which files you've modified and check them out for you.  You can use the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963) to scan your local disk for changes that were made using the command:

```
tfpt online
```

This will locate files that were modified and not checked out as well as files that were added to your disk that don't have a corresponding add pended and files that were removed that don't have a corresponding delete pended.  You can then choose to pend any or all of those changes to the server and then checkin.

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the modified files to another directory, check the files out that you have modified, then copy over the files with the new/modified ones and then check them back in.

Comment: Ok thank you is there a way to check out multiple files in tfs 2010 in single operation.

Comment: Yes, from the solution explorer, select multiple files by holding down the left-shift key, and then right click to check them out all at once. Check them all back in the same way.

Comment: That should be the CTRL key, not the shift key

Comment: You don't have to copy the files first. If you don't have the option "Get latest on checkout" set, then it only marks the file as being checked out and removes the readonly bit.