# Manually update files

Tags: tfs

Scenario:

A solution is checked into TFS.  Changes are made to an offline/disconnected/unbound copy of the solution, which becomes "the latest" version.  I want to update the repo with this disconnected copy's files.

How do I get TFS to look at all the files and determine which ones have changed, so it can check only those in?

If this were SVN, I would just plop the files on top of the existing working copy, and it would just work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anyway in TFS to check-in modified files which are not checked-out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528046/anyway-in-tfs-to-check-in-modified-files-which-are-not-checked-out)

Comment: dont worry, I dont think he is asking anything similar. I have had to rollback files before and the best way was to download the old version of the file and replace the existing file with it because TFS doesn't have a simple rollback option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have another copy of the solution that is bound to TFS?  If not, you'll need one.  You have two options:

1. Take the solution "offline" by right-clicking on the solution node and click "Go Offline".  You can then copy your changed solution on top of the bound solution.  When you load the solution again, right-click the solution again and choose Go Online.  This will scan the disk and determine what has changed.
2. You other options is to run "tf edit" recursively on a bound solution, copy your changed solution on top of the bound one and then run "tfpt uu".  "uu" stands for undo unchanged and it will undo changes to the files that are not different.

Answer (score 0):

I cant think of any elegant way off hand but your best option would be to know what files were changed or added offline and connect them to the TFS version while removing the old TFS files.

To do this simply right click all of the old files and either delete them or exclude them from the project then move the new files into their physical folders and replace them with the updated version. If  files were added then add them in the correct folders. Finally make sure all files are view-able in the solution explorer by clicking "show all files". Finally, right click the files you changed and select include in project for each.

This way you will have replaced only the files that were changed and won't have to check in the entire solution to TFS making it very unclear what files were changed with your check-in.